# CodeIgniter - Method to redirect() to another page with an extra string to output as html?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-redirect

I'm using CodeIgniter and trying to redirect back to the controller with a "status update" after an action url has been run... I can explain this better.. So I have an admin page "*example.com/admin*" and I manage users at "*/admin/users*" and When i delete a user it goes to "*/admin/delete_user*". I want it to redirect BACK to "*/admin/users*" and add a variable set like $status_update with a **success** or **failure** message.

How could I get a message back to the other view? Here's my simplified code.
**My full code is actually full of security measures so ignore it's lack of currently.*

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('admin/admin');
    }     
    public function users(){                   // admin/users
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $users = $this->user_model->get();
        $this->load->view('admin/users', ['users' => $users]);
    }
    public function delete_user($user_id){     // admin/delete_user
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        if ($this->user_model->delete($user_id) == true){
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $users = $this->user_model->get();
            $this->load->view('admin/users', ['users' => $users]);

                // I WANT THIS TO GO BACK TO "/admin/users" WITH THE STATEMENT BELOW

            echo $user_id . ' has been deleted from the system';
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong trying to delete ' . $user_id;
        }
    }
}
```

How could I go about this? The only way I can see about going something like this is by moving the delete function into the users function and call it with a form submission variable but I feel like there might be a better way.
I hope my question makes sense.

### Update

Thanks to tomexsans & saurabh2836 I ended up solving this with a small addition to the end

I moved the actual call into the view itself because of complications with sending an additional array into the view from the controller wasn't going well but I also had a small issue where the flash data was lasting through the request and then through a second which was causing problems and I fixed that with the following

```
<?php if ($this->session->flashdata('message') !== null){
        $_session_data = $this->session->flashdata('message');
        $message = $_session_data['message'];
        $status = $_session_data['status'];
        if ($status == 'success'){
            echo '<div class="alert-success"><strong>'.$message.'</strong></div>';
        } elseif ($status == 'failed'){
            echo '<div class="alert-danger"><strong>'.$message.'</strong></div>';
        }
        $this->session->unset_userdata('flash_message'); //this fixed data showing after another request.
    } ?>
```

### Update 2

For future users looking to use this method I found a strange happenstance where if you make the request with a  tag it won't display as you'd think (I have a feeling it has something to do with browser caching) so to fix this you have to make calls through a form. This is how I implemented my method.

```
<form action="<?=site_url("admin/delete_user/{$_value->user_id}")?>" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

I know it's a bit much compared to a link but I don't want to rely Javascript to submit a form. Have another idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do a shortcut to this also

Check this for above answer

**In Controller**

`$this->session->set_flashdata('message','<p>'.$user_id . ' has been deleted from the system .$status</p>);`

**In View**

```
   <?php if($this->session->flashdata('message')) echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
```

To use this flashdata for more then one time you can use

```
$this->session->keep_flashdata('item');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `flashdata`

```
//sample with HTML

$data['message'] = '<p>'.$user_id . ' has been deleted from the system</p>';
$data['status'] = 'good';
$this->session->set_flashdata('message',$data);
redirect('admin/users');


//and on your controller admin users just get the message by:

$_session_data = $this->session->flashdata('message');
$data['message'] = $_session_data['message'];
$data['status'] = $_session_data['status'];
//load in view
$this->load->view('page',$data);
```

Read more about this at [Sessions Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)